# NGINX Password Dialog won't go away

Tags: nginx

I've enabled password protection on one sub-domain using NGINX and wrote a little script that will allow adding users easily. When I enter the password though, the dialog goes away and immediately pops up again.

Here's my password generator script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "Username Expected as first param"
elif [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    echo "Password Expected as second param"
else
  htpasswd -b /home/me/.passwords $1 $2
  /etc/init.d/nginx reload
fi
```

Running:

`./create-password test password`

I can see the following output:

> Adding password for user test
>
> [ ok ] Reloading nginx configuration (via systemctl): nginx.service.

Inside `/home/me/.passwords` I can see the following entry:

```
test:$apr1$t.LpBHkW$bEBEMK1HRBqAvvkB9cQ.I.
```

Inside my nginx config (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blah`), I have the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name blah.example.com;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file  /home/me/.passwords;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:6999;
                proxy_redirect  off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

[image]

If I type in `test` and `testing`,

[image]

the dialog would go away and pop up again.

[image]

I'm not seeing any errors in the NGINX `error.log`, `access.log` only shows which is basically an error 401, Unauthorized:

```
___.___.___.___ - test [16/Apr/2016:09:36:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 1421 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623
.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Cancelling the password popup, I see the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Jenkins on that subdomain, the moment I changed my http username and password to match that of the Jenkins username and password, it worked.

Jenkins is probably using http auth headers as well.